# Add page in the middle of itextsharp

Tags: itext

I'm creating a PDF using iTextSharp and after adding all my pages, I want to be able to add a table of contents at the beginning.  Is there a way to "rewind" the PDFWriter?

```
var d = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
d.Open();
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    d.Add(new Paragraph("Hola Senor Page:" + w.CurrentPageNumber.ToString()));
}

w.GoToPage1;
d.Add("Table of Contents here");

d.Close();
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not like that, no.  After a writer leaves a given page, everything for that page is written to the output stream.  Any page-relative links are already embedded.

There's an example or two of how to build ToC's floating around on the web somewhere, lets see if I can dig one up...

[Ah!  So while the individual pages are written out as you build them, you can change their order prior to writing everything out.](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=98)

In the above example, they build the TOC last, and then shuffle it to the front prior to saving the PDF.  Learn something new every day.